# Qual é a diferença entre "despedir-se de" e "despedir-se"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões

Qual é diferença entre **despedir-se de** e **despedir-se**?

Eu sei que despedir-se significa tchau, mas a outra também?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É a mesma coisa, simplesmente com *despedir-se de* estamos a dar informação extra -- quem foi cumprimentado ou de que trabalho uma pessoa se demitiu.

- O João despediu-se (da Marta).
- O João despediu-se (do seu terceiro emprego em 3 meses).

Comment: Artefacto Eu vi que uma pessoa disse que "ela quer despedir-se de uma casa" e por isso eu pensei que isso significa falar tchau para sempre! 
Isso não é o caso?

Comment: @Majid   É muito unusual alguém despedir-se de uma casa. (say good-bye to a/one's home) mas é possível. Você pode despedir-se de um cão, de um móvel, daquilo que você quiser.  Mas é meio estranho.  Quando a despedida é para sempre, geralmente "dizemos **adeus** à/ao".

Comment: @centaurus discordo inteiramente. Não há nenhuma incompatibilidade entre a expressão "despedir-se" e o fato de ser para sempre. A escolha entre os dois termos é meramente estilística. Não acho que "adeus" seria opção preferencial para despedidas definitivas.

Comment: @mguima  Você não entendeu bem o que eu escrevi.  Quando queremos deixar claro que uma despedida é para sempre, **geralmente** dizemos "adeus".  "Despedir-se" pode ser para sempre ou não, o contexto é que vai deixar claro.

Comment: @centaurus 1. Não me parece polido iniciar uma comunicação com uma frase do tipo "você não entendeu". 2. Não sei qual seu conhecimento de português,  se és nativo, mas "muito unusual" (a expressão que usaste) não so Seria BEM preferível algo como "não é muito usual". Unusual não é português.  Deves estar for a de tua terra há tanto tempo que já começou a esquecer. 3. A parte do "geralmente dizemos" fica por tua conta. Eu discordo de que haja uma preferência por "adeus" em caso de permanência ou definitividade. 4. Não estou fora de minha terra e não estou confundindo idiomas.

Comment: Houve um errinho no meu comentário anterior que não consegui corrigir. Eu pretendia dizer que "muito unusual" é uma expressão inexistente em português. Provavelmente tradução literal de very unusual.

Comment: @mguima 1.Tampouco  me parece muito polido fazer suposições sobre o estado da minha memória  (" Deves estar fora de tua terra há tanto tempo que já começ**aste** a esquecer.") 2. Não pretendo levar adiante uma discussão inútil.